# twbs pagination not displaying data

Tags: javascript, jquery

My html header:

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
   <script type = "text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twbs-pagination/1.4.1/jquery.twbsPagination.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

jquery:

```
function apply_pagination() {
            console.log("apply_pagination called")
            console.log("total pages", totalPages)
            $pagination.twbsPagination({
                totalPages: totalPages,
                visiblePages: 6,
                onPageClick: function (event, page) {
                    displayRecordsIndex = Math.max(page - 1, 0) * recPerPage;
                    endRec = (displayRecordsIndex) + recPerPage;
                    displayRecords = records.slice(displayRecordsIndex, endRec);
                    console.log("i am inside onpageclick");
                    generate_table();
                }
            });
        }
```

html:

```
   <div class="container">                                                                               
    <div class="table-responsive">   
    <h2>View Installment Details</h2>     
    <table class="table">
        <tbody id="emp_body">
            <tr>
                <th>Customer ID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Transaction ID</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>First Due Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>First Due Date</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Second Due Amount</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Second Due Date</th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="pager">
        <ul id="pagination" class="pagination-lg"></ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The console.log inside onPageClick is not being called. Is there a reason why ? It works in my staging environment but not in production.

EDITED:
Added html code for pagination. It works well in staging but not production.

Comment: Where is `$pagination` defined? Any error on console?

Comment: var $pagination = $('#pagination') @AmmoPT

Comment: But it's not in the code provided, and is `#pagination` a `ul` element?

Comment: @AmmoPT yes it is. >>  <div id="pager">
        <ul id="pagination" class="pagination-lg"></ul>
    </div>

Comment: @AmmoPT could it be the header of my html file for including too many jquery ?

Comment: Can you include the `HTML` you're referring to in your question? Your jQuery imports look fine to me.

Comment: @AmmoPT added for your reference.

Comment: What comes before `apply_pagination()` ? From the code provided, `totalPages` is not defined. The code you're providing does not run. The reason that works in staging and not in production is probably because somewhere else these variables are being defined.

Comment: @AmmoPT totalPages is defined and it has the value of 1.

Comment: There's your problem. totalPages needs to be at least 2. Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dn8jsawe/16/). It only works when totalPages is `>2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for [twbs pagination](https://github.com/josecebe/twbs-pagination) to not display data is because your variable `totalPages` has a value of `1`, as per this [code function](https://github.com/josecebe/twbs-pagination/blob/master/jquery.twbsPagination.js#L43):

```
// hide if only one page exists
if (this.options.hideOnlyOnePage && this.options.totalPages == 1) {
    if (this.options.initiateStartPageClick) {
        this.$element.trigger('page', 1);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Make sure `totalPages` is `>1` or it won't display any pager.

Comment: Hi Do you have any idea of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62427881/twbs-pagination-unable-to-load-new-page-data-in-datatable ... could you please have a look